# Scheduling an apex batch

Tags: apex, batch, schedule

I have a batch and now I want to create a schedulable class to run the batch every Saturday at 1AM. I was following the salesforce docs but cannot seem to grasp everything correctly.

Here's my schedulable class code

```
global class SchedulableClass implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        IndependentBatch b = new IndependentBatch();
        database.executebatch(b);
    }
    SchedulableClass saturday1am = new SchedulableClass();
    String sch = '0 0 01 ? * 7';
    String jobId = system.schedule('sat1am', sch, saturday1am);
}
```

How do I activate this class? Is my syntax correct? Am I supposed to move the string sch and system.schedule inside the execute? If so do I remove the database.executebatch(b) in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
SchedulableClass saturday1am = new SchedulableClass();
String sch = '0 0 01 ? * 7';
String jobId = system.schedule('sat1am', sch, saturday1am);
```

Needs to be outside of that class, since that is the code that schedules your job.

You can either put that code inside another class, or run it from "Execute Anonymous".

Comment: I would add to this. Or simply schedule it through the system interface. Setup => Develop => Apex Classes => Schedule Apex.

Comment: Where do I put that code inside the rest of my apex code? Do I put it in the controller of the visualforce page?

Comment: @JesseMilburn - thanks for the suggestion. I already researched that, now I wanted to see how I can do it with strictly apex code as well. Thank you.

Comment: The Controller of a VF page is a perfect place for it, I would hook it up to a button (so a user can click something to schedule it)

Comment: You can also simply run it in an "Execute Anoynmous" console

Comment: You're welcome! If it works for you, make sure to mark the solution as accepted so others can benefit!

Answer (score 4):

Just a note, you can implement `Schedulable` in the same class as your `Batchable`. No need to write them separately.

```
public class MySchedulableBatch implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) { Database.executeBatch(this); }
    // Database.Batchable implementation
}
```

Comment: Man, that's beautiful. Thank you for letting me know!